# Downgrade from Tensorflow 2.x to 1.15

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm running into an issue where I'm unable to downgrade to tensorflow 1.15.

As of now I have the latest version of tf but I'm running into the 'AttributeError module `'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib''` error. I've read that this can be fixed by downgrading to tf 1.15 but when I run `pip3 install tensorflow==1.15` I get this: `"ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.15 (from versions: 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.3.0rc0, 2.3.0rc1, 2.3.0rc2, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.4.0rc0, 2.4.0rc1, 2.4.0rc2, 2.4.0rc3)`
ERROR: `No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.15"`

What should I do to fix my attribute error?

Comment: Is downgrading the only way to fix your problem?  I'd try something else before doing that.

Comment: Do not mix tensorflow 2 and 1.5 dependencies rather create seprate virtual envs for both versions with their dendencies.

Answer (score 0):

version 1.15.0 should work

```
pip install tensorflow==1.15.0
```

you can check all available distributions for tensorflow on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#history).